# How can I acquire data from live experimentation and do a live 2D plot using threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, plot

I need to take data from an instrument and live 2D plot them. I can do it without threads, but it is slow ... How could I proceed without having errors like "QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread", "QApplication: Object event filter cannot be in a different thread" and "QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread". I used this code as a test:

```
    import threading
    import time
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   class myThread (threading.Thread):
      def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.threadID = threadID
      self.name = name
      self.counter = counter
      s=(6,6)

      self.x=np.zeros(s)
      def run(self):
         print "Starting " + self.name
         threadLock.acquire()

         if self.threadID==1:
           acquire_data(self.x)
           count_to_three(self.name,1)
           plot_it(self.x)
           count_to_three(self.name,1)
           print "Exiting "+ self.name

         if self.threadID==2:
            count_to_three(self.name,1)
            print "Exiting "+ self.name

         threadLock.release()


 def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
    time.sleep(delay)
    print "%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()))
    counter -= 1
def count_to_three(threadName,delay):
   i=0
   while i<4:
       time.sleep(delay)
       print"%s: %s" % (threadName,i)
       i+=1

def acquire_data(x):

   return

def plot_it(x):
  sidex = np.linspace(0,6,6) 
  sidey = np.linspace(0,6,6)
  X,Y = np.meshgrid(sidex,sidey)
  plt.subplot(111)
  plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,x)

  return
  # Create new threads


  plt.figure()
  threadLock=threading.Lock()
  while True:

     threads=[]
     thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 3)
     thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)

    # Start new Threads
     thread1.start()
     thread2.start()

   # Add threads to thread list
   threads.append(thread1)
   threads.append(thread2)

   for t in threads:
      plt.show()
      t.join()
```

Comment: To get data from an instrument you can use PyDAQ. Don't you need the data to be presented all in one plot?

Comment: I can get data and put them in text, and I'm fine with that. What I am actually asking for is live update the figure each time a new data is taken using threads.

Comment: Your question didn't sound like that. Then, put matplotlib in interactive mode, so that it will be updated each time you do a plot or something. It would be wise to use matplotlib in object oriented style when dealing with threads.

Comment: Ok, I'll look at it that way. Thanks!